# TCDL TagLib support in Web 8 for Component Links

Tags: web8, dynamic-linking

In Tridion 2011 we use the TCDL taglib for our Tridion Component Links.  Our published .aspx page has the following code.  (example from https://tridionbasicscity.com/2015/05/05/tcdl-tridion-content-deployment-language-basics-i/)

```
<tridion:ComponentLink runat="server" PageURI="tcm:123-250233-64" 
         ComponentURI="tcm:123-654674" TemplateURI="tcm:0-0-0" AddAnchor="false" 
         LinkText="Product" LinkAttributes="" class="productSection" 
         title="Product" " TextOnFail="true" />
```

Does SDL Web 8 provide a taglib for this functionality?  If not, what is the suggested upgrade process to move from the taglib to the supported Web 8 method for Component Links?

Error:

> Parser Error Message: Unknown server tag 'tridion:ComponentLink'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .NET controls you mention are still shipped and configured the same way.

Since the error is about the tag 'tridion:ComponentLink' not being recognized, I would suggest you check the relevant web.config file on your site and ensure that the 'tridion' prefix is configured correctly:

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="tridion" namespace="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.UI" assembly="Tridion.ContentDelivery"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
```